# Twitter's bootstrap typeahead - how to allow values from the list only?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to allow user to choose values from predefined list only with Twitter's bootstrap typeahead? Ideally, each text value should be replaced with some numeric value (how it is possible with `select`).

For ex.:

```
var regionsList = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];
var regionsCodesList = [11, 12, 77];
$('#region').typeahead({ source: regionsList });
```

User should be able to input only *value1*, *value2* or *value3* and nothing more. Once form is submitted values like *11*, *12*, *77* should be passed accordingly.

Upd. I've created custom validation method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("validRegion", function (value, element, param) {
  return !(param.indexOf(value) == -1);
}, "Please start to input the region and then choose the value from the list");
```

`regionsList` is passed as `param`. But it doesn't work well - if user chooses the value from the list with mouse, then error message is not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try the update method:

```
$('#region').typeahead({ 
   // ....  
   "updater" : function bla(item) {
       $('#region').val(item);
       $("#myForm").validate().element("#region");
       return item;         }
   } 
}
```